# Target all nested li of chosen parent li

Tags: jquery

I have three unordered lists nested in each other. Second and third `ul` is hided (`display: none;`)

By first event i need to show all `ul.second` elements of first `li` of `ul.first`.

By second event i need to show all `ul.third` elements of first `li` of `ul.second`.
Here is the code:

**HTML**

```
<ul class="first">
<li class="first-element">
    <ul class="second">
        <li class="second-element">
            <ul class="third">
                <li class="third-element"></li>
                <li class="third-element"></li>
                <li class="third-element"></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="second-element">
            <ul class="third">
                <li class="third-element"></li>
                <li class="third-element"></li>
                <li class="third-element"></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="second-element">
            <ul class="third">
                <li class="third-element"></li>
                <li class="third-element"></li>
                <li class="third-element"></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="first-element">
    <ul class="second">
        <li class="second-element">
            <ul class="third">
                <li class="third-element"></li>
                <li class="third-element"></li>
                <li class="third-element"></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="second-element">
            <ul class="third">
                <li class="third-element"></li>
                <li class="third-element"></li>
                <li class="third-element"></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="second-element">
            <ul class="third">
                <li class="third-element"></li>
                <li class="third-element"></li>
                <li class="third-element"></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul.second li {
    display: none;
}
ul.third li {
    display: none;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('li.first-element:eq(0) li.second-element').show(); // works fine, it shows only li.second-element of ul.first first li
$('li.second-element:eq(0) li.third-element').show(); // does not work, in log it gives me empty []
```

How to target `li.second-element:eq(0) li.third-element` in other way ?

Comment: Do you want to create an hover effect or something? Like the programs menu of Windows? If not, please explain what triggers these shows and hides.

Comment: @Sven You absolutly right, i want to create menu like in windows programms. By first event on mouseover on `ul.first li:eq(0)` i will show all `ul.second li` nested in `ul.first li:eq(0)`.On second event on mouseover on `ul.second li:eq(0`) i will show all `ul.third li` nested in `ul.second li:eq(0)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

then

```
$('.first li:eq(0) .second > li');
$('.second > li:eq(0) .third > li');
```

Comment: This will target all `ul.second li`, i need to target all `ul.second li` nested only in `ul.first li:eq(0)`

Comment: By the way it works perfect in jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/lesnick/8qE9f/. As well as my variant `$('li.second-element:eq(0) li.third-element').show();`

Comment: Hm, i attached latest version of jquery and evrything goes ok. Thank you.